# For Java drawImage, what does sx mean?

Tags: java, drawimage

Recently I've been trying to improve my overall java programming abilities, so I was searching the Java API docs and came across a the drawImage method (for Graphics). One iteration of the method has 
"drawImage(Image img, int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2, int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, int sy2, ImageObserver observer)"

I'm can't figure out what the sx and sy's are for, and an  explanation of exactly how dx and dy work would be appreciated as well. Thanks!

Comment: [From the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) - *"sx1 - the x coordinate of the first corner of the source rectangle.
sy1 - the y coordinate of the first corner of the source rectangle.
sx2 - the x coordinate of the second corner of the source rectangle.
sy2 - the y coordinate of the second corner of the source rectangle.*"

Comment: If only there were such a thing as the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) where this could be looked up.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation given on the Java Tutorials page gives a clearer explanation of the drawImage function:

```
 boolean Graphics.drawImage(Image img,
        int dstx1, int dsty1, int dstx2, int dsty2,
        int srcx1, int srcy1, int srcx2, int srcy2,
        ImageObserver observer);
```

"The src parameters represent the area of the image to copy and draw. The dst parameters display the area of the destination to cover by the the source area. The dstx1, dsty1 coordinates define the location to draw the image. The width and height dimensions on the destination area are calculated by the following expressions: (dstx2-dstx1), (dsty2-dsty1). If the dimensions of the source and destinations areas are different, the Java 2D API will scale up or scale down, as needed."

In another words, the coordinate (srcx1, srcy1) is the upper left hand corner of the region you want to copy. and (srcx2, srcy2) is the bottom right hand coordinate.

(dstx1, dstx2) is the upper left coordinate of the begin point to start drawing the source image, and (dstx2,dsty2) is the bottom right coordinate of destination region.

Here is the corresponding link you can reference - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html